# Run an application as administrator via registry key (HKLM\...\WinLogon, Shell)

Tags: windows, vb.net, visual-studio, registry

I've developed a vb.net (Visual Studio 2017, .net framework 4.6.1) application which should be executed at system startup replacing "explorer" in Windows 10.
To do so, I've modified the reg key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Winlogon
```

And Reg value:

```
Shell="explorer"
```

replacing it with my application file name.

That works fine, but I also need to run my application as administrator.
I could check "run as administrator" checkbox on exe properties, or declare it on app.manifest of my VS project:

```
<requestedExecutionLevel level="highestAvailable" uiAccess="false" />
```

These solution block Windows registry to run my application on startup using `Shell` value.

So, I'm asking you if there is any way to run an application with administrator rights using `Shell` registry value (or something else).

Thank you very much.
Dave.

Comment: Any luck on this, I have the exact same problem!

Comment: Same issue, any solution??

Comment: When you set a program to "always run as admin" using the Windows compat troubleshooter, it writes a value in `Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\AppCompatFlags\Layers` with the complete binary path as the Key and the Data as `^ RUNASADMIN`

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem with a Kiosk app that could not run properly because it didn't had an admin privilege. So instead of granting it admin privileges, I've just lowered down the entire UAC with the reg key:

```
HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System
```

with Reg value:

```
EnableLUA = 0
```

Since then, my app's running without any authorization issues.

It might not be straight up solution you look for, but it is an alternative you can think of...

Answer (score 0):

alternative you can create a Task in **Task Scheduler** with Admin Rights, and u can set Shell value to C:\Windows\System32\schtasks.exe /run /tn "LaserTracApp"

in my case i create a Shell key here  Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\WinLogon